# How to Add React Js On an Existing html page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I create React application using `npx create-react-app my-app`. I want to add this React application to my existing HTML in a specific `<div>`.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Client</title>
  
</head>
<body onload="QueryDetails()">
  <div align="center">
    <label for="clientList">Client List</label>
    <div id="clientDetails" />                          //loading the table here 
                                                         and it should be react 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="../../../../../clientDetails.js"></script>  //added the script whch has func to displaytable
```

clientDetails.js // which is basically getting json response from server and display a table.

```
function QueryDetails() {
  get(url + "clientDetails?", "clientDetails",

        function () {
            var clientDetails  = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            var table = createTable(["Name", "Date of Birth", "Gender", "ID"]);
            table.align = "center";

            // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
            for (var i = 0; i < clientDetails.length; ++i) {
              var name = clientDetails[Name].Value[0];
              var id = clientDetails[Id].Value[0];
              var nameCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
              nameCell.innerHTML = name;
              var idCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
              idCell.innerHTML = name;
            }

            // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
            var divContainer = document.getElementById("clientDetails");
            divContainer.innerHTML = "";
            divContainer.appendChild(table);
        }
    );
}
```

Now I have created a react app using create-react-app and I try to add this clientDetails.js inside src folder and somehow run the react in my existing html page.

Is that possible? If yes, what would be the steps to do?

Is my understanding correct:

1. in my-app remove the App.js and add clientDetails.js
2. now use webpack may be to create a bundle.js and that bundle.js should be added in script tag in my existing html ??

Answer (score 0):

What is your goal? Is there any React code you created? Or do you just hope your existing JavaScript would run somehow faster or better, unchanged but put it into some React wrapper?